# Generating a tree visualization in java

Tags: java, visualization

I don't know what is the name of this visualization type, but I want to learn how to draw trees like the ones in this image:

[image]

I've seen this kind of visualization in many sites but I'm unable to know the technical term behind it.

Comment: You'll want to research graph layout algorithms; there are a zillion. Or you could just use Processing, which includes many already.

Comment: you want to draw this as an image or you want to render it via HTML ?

Answer (score 5):

That graph seems a lot like a [force-directed layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). Painting those kind of images is not an easy task, depending on what are you trying to accomplish, you might want to use an existing framwork. If you want to use java you should see at [gephi](http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Dev_portal), if you can use an html approach you should definitely take a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) which is a javascript library for data visualization. They have neat examples: [directed-force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), and [collapsible-force layout](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html).

Comment: it's not only the layout, it's the trees themselves. How to draw them? their names ....

Comment: @guckogucko I am not sure I follow your question, a tree is only a particular case of a directed graph. The way the drawing is accomplished depends on the algorithm used. Simulated Annealing can give good results.

Answer (score 4):

This particular image is done by Stephanie Posavec. You can learn about her design process from an interview she gave the folks at the [Data Stories podcast](http://datastori.es/data-stories-10-hand-crafted-data-with-stefanie-posavec/). As far as I remember it, she partially crafts her visualizations by hand, so I'm not sure if you'll ever find an algorithm that does exactly this for you. For different tree layout algorithms, you can refer to [treevis.net](http://treevis.net).